# Relaxing a binary variable in a Mix Integer Programming problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, constraints, constraint-programming

I am quite new to the field of optimization and currently having a problem of formulating a constraint with binary variable.

For each value of $b$, if there exists one value of k such that $z_1[b, k]$ or $z_2[b, k]$ or $z_3[b, k]$ is greater than $0$, then set all other values of $z_1[b, k], z_2[b, k], z_3[b, k]$ to $0$ for that particular $b$.

Because $z$ is binary, it is quite easy, the constraint should be $sum(z) <= 1$.

Now, I want to relax binary variable, so the constraint $sum(z) <= 1$ is not true any more.

I came up with the idea to rewrite this constraint as: $sum(z) == max(z)$ for each $b$, but it seems not to be a convex constraint.

Is there any way to formulate it as a convex constraint?

Thank you,

Comment: $\sum_{i \neq j} z_i z_j \leq 0$ ensures that atmost one variable is positive (if two, then their product would make the LHS $> 0$). Though I don't know if this is convex.